# Find point where values in array start decreasing in Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, dataframe, max

I've got an data frame array[time][Gforce] of values that represent data collected from the motion of a Pendulum.

It looks something like this:

time    TgF

0        0.993

1        0.988

2        0.982

3        0.983

......

36882    1.002

36883    1.000

Plotted, it looks something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfF4N.png
(Not enough reputaion to post image?)

The Gforce Value stays pretty much the same in the begging and end than it starts oscillating: Getting bigger till a maximum, than getting smaller to a minimum(sort of).

What I need is to find at which times does the "shift" occurs, for example:

time               TgF

5.23               0.228

5.237              0.195

5.241              **0.194**

5.245              0.203

5.251              0.238

I could use a loop, and that would be easy to implement, such as:

```
p1 = pandas.read_csv('Pendulo 1.csv', sep=',')
for i in range(1070, p1.TgF.size):
    if(p1.TgF[i] > p1.TgF[i+1] and p1.TgF[i+1] < p1.TgF[i+2]):
        print(p1.time[i+1])
        break
```

But I feel it would be too slow for the amount of data I have(36884 data points). Is there a better way using some Python wizardry?

Ps.: It's my first question on StackOverflow, hope it was well laid out :)

Answer (score 0):

The same result may be achieved with:

```
p1["shift_f"] = p1["TgF"].shift(1).bfill()
p1["shift_b"] = p1["TgF"].shift(-1).ffill()

oscillating_ix = p1["TgF"] < p1[["shift_b", "shift_f"]].min(1)

p1.loc[oscillating_ix].drop(["shift_b", "shift_f"], axis=1)
```